# Matplotlib problems with colors and line cycles

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm writing a small class containing all the parameters suitable for my needs, 
but I came across a problem when I define the 3 cycles to be accomplish. 
What I' do is : define 3 type of cycle (cycle0, cycle1, cycle2) and then in a dictionary containing several `rcParams` i set `'axes.prop_cycle'`
the 3 cycle are defined as follow:

```
cycle0 =  plt.cycler("color", colors)         
cycle1 = plt.cycler("color", colors) + plt.cycler("linestyle", linestyles)
cycle2 = plt.cycler("color", colors) * plt.cycler("linestyle", linestyles)
```

the problem appars when I chose to use cycle0 :

```
'axes.prop_cycle': cycle0,
```

and the set of the colors (that I choose) have a different length respect the linestyle but with cycle0 I don't wan't use the linestyle !
how can I manage this problem ? so far I have to comment out cycle1 when I have to use cycle0 and comment out cycle1 when I wabt to use its

**EDIT** 
the error is this one :

```
ValueError: Can only add equal length cycles, not 6 and 8
```

but in myparams definition I'm use

```
'axes.prop_cycle': cycle0,
```

**EDIT**
minimum compilable example :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def _plot(*args,**kwargs):

    linestyles  = [(0, ()),(0, (1, 1)),(0, (5, 10)),(0, (5, 5)),(0, (5, 1)),(0, (3, 10, 1, 10)),(0, (3, 5, 1, 5)),(0, (3, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5)) ]
    colors      = ['#3B4CC0','#7C9FF9','#C0D4F5','#F2CBB7','#EE8568','#B40426']

    variable = [*args]
    if len(variable) % 3 != 0:
      print('Error variable must be coupled (even number)')
      raise AttributeError('you must give 2 array x,y followed by string label for each plot')

    parameters = {**kwargs} 

    cycle0 =  plt.cycler("color", colors) 
    cycle1 = plt.cycler("color", colors) + plt.cycler("linestyle", linestyles)
    cycle2 = plt.cycler("color", colors) * plt.cycler("linestyle", linestyles)


    myparams = {
        'axes.prop_cycle': cycle0  
     }

    plt.rcParams.update(myparams)
    fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,figsize=(7,4.2))

    for i in range(0,len(variable)-1,3):
            plt.plot(variable[i],variable[i+1], linewidth=3, label= variable[i+2])
    plt.grid(linestyle='--', dashes=(5,7))
    plt.show() 



def main():

    x  = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
    y1 = np.sin(x) 
    y2 = np.sin(2*x)
    y3 = np.sin(4*x)

    _plot(x,y1,'sin(x)',x,y2,'sin(2x)',x,y3,'sin(3x)')


if __name__ == '__main__' :
    main()
```

If instead you comment cycle1 this works !

**EDIT** Maybe I'm not explain well , this code ( cycle1 ) is a cycle that I used 
with different scheme of colors .. the one that I've reported is just an example that Say :

Also if I alco use cycle0 in the rcParams list (here I've Reported) just the scheme of colors blue to red. but in my class there is a lot of scheme of colors and also a lot of linestyles .... the parameters that appears in

```
myparams = {
        ......
        'axes.prop_cycle': cycle0  
        ......
         }
```

is given from a dictionary (looks the definition of _plot) and I want fiugure out which is a way to have this cycle1 as option of my `'axes.prop_cycle'` in this way I can switch with out comment or uncomment this line of code (cycle1 ....)

Comment: Seems you have written this in a bit of a hurry? What *is* the problem you encounter?

Comment: This needs a [mcve].

Comment: What would be your desired output then? Trimming the longer cycler? Repeating the shorter one? Imho multiplication, what you already have detected, is the best way to combine cyclers of unequal length. What is your problem with that?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `cycle1`, not `cycle0`. You may remove that line, because it is never used in the code.
Else you need to make sure to have equal length cyclers.

E.g you could add two more colors to the color cycle

```
colors = ['#3B4CC0','#7C9FF9','#C0D4F5','#F2CBB7','#EE8568','#B40426', "red", "limegreen"]
```

such that both, linestyles and colors have 8 elements.